# Gmap basic map display

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to use the gmap3 JQuery plugin to set a basic map on my html file but always when I'm refreshing my page there's nothing. Here's my code: http://pastie.org/8062410
It says on this link how to setup and normally it's just one JQuery line: http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/9-map/map-32

Someone can help me to find out what's happen with my code please ? Thanks for your help!

---

I come back to this topic because there's other issues with JQM + Google Map API V3. I want to create a full screen google map with a simple header which contains my logo and a small button to open a right-side JQM Panel. Here is my code which display a JQM header + the open panel button (it work's !):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>TEST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/default-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3. /jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?k&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./gmap3v5.1.1/gmap3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/load-map.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="interface">
    <div data-role="header">
        <div id=logo>
            <img src="../../images/logo.png" width="56" height="25">
        </div>
        <a href="#openPanel">Panel</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="openPanel" data-role="panel" data-position="right" data-display="overlay">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="e">
            <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      <script>
        $("#map-page").gmap3();
      </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the Google Map never appear in full-screen and sometimes it hide my header. Someone can tell me what's wrong with my DOM ? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Pls post your code here, and maybe you're missing google map api `key`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I added my API key, it's just I leave it for this snippet.

Comment: Oh, you're using jQM. where is `#test` in your code?

Comment: Yes also, I don't know if it comes from JQM but it's weird!

Comment: you want to show the map in a div with id `#test` but it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

test div is missing. the below code is working fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Gmap3 test</title>

        <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="gmap3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" data-theme="a">

            <div id="test" style="width:500px;height:500px;">

            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <script>
                    $("#test").gmap3({
                        map:{
                            address:"POURRIERES, FRANCE",
                            options:{
                                zoom:4,
                                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
                                mapTypeControl: true,
                                mapTypeControlOptions: {
                                    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
                                },
                                navigationControl: true,
                                scrollwheel: true,
                                streetViewControl: true
                            }
                        }
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Katcha - i verified it in firefox as well as chrome.. its working fine.  can u plz tell which browser & version u checking.

Comment: @Katcha : did u included jquery library. In my code i added 1.7.2 for test purpose..  did u include it properly.

Comment: Just copy my code and place it in html file and include gmap and jquery js files properly. surely, it will work.

Comment: satfish, thanks mate, it work fine now, it was a weird error with my JQuery lib include, thanks again!

Comment: This will never work correctly with jQuery Mobile. To be more precise this solution will never cover full screen even if you change width and height to 100%.

Comment: Hi Gajotres, Thanks for your interesting comment because it's true, I struggle to fit my map with JQM, sometimes the map disappear and sometimes it's my header. What's the solution to use JQM + Google map API V3 properly and make it works ?